# Configure and Test Ethernet, Wi-fi and Bluetooth Peripherals in Android Thing Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-things, bluetooth-peripheral

I developed an Android App to test the peripherals in an Android Thing using the information given in the link https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/pio/gpio. The link has given support to configure and test GPIO, SPI, UART, I2C and PWM, similarly I want to test Ethernet, Wifi and Bluetooth.

---

Is there any options to configure and test Ethernet, Wifi and Bluetooth peripherals in Android things.

Answer (score 0):

Android Things is based on Android. As such, Ethernet, Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth features use the same APIs and capabilities as [the standard Android platform](https://developer.android.com/reference). For Bluetooth, the platform provides [some additional APIs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/bluetooth) for features like pairing.

Comment: Thank you, I got an idea. Could you please let me know what package should I use to configure and test Ethernet Peripheral !

Comment: You should start on the [Android connectivity documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity) and further investigate in that vein.

Answer (score 0):

Android things exposes a set of APIs that enable you to control various peripherals.

The [Android Things Bluetooth APIs](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/bluetooth) extends the basic android bluetooth APIs that shall provide access to Bluetooth functionality and this can be used for configuration and verification of bluetooth.

At connectivity level, the [connectivity manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager) shall be of great help in monitoring and verification of various network connectivity status and related functionalities in ethernet and wireless.

The [WiFi manager APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager) enable communication with wireless stack which can be used in managing/checking Wi-Fi specific operations.

In case if you want to validate your development features or driver changes on network connectivity part of stack (Bluetooth, Cellular and Wi-Fi), the [Android Connectivity Testing Suite (ACTS)](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/connect_tests)  can help for verification of functionality and stability.